# Grid start error after upgrading from GridGain 6.1.6 to 6.2.0

Tags: gridgain

I'm attempting to upgrade our gridgain  install from 6.1.6 to 6.2.0 (tried 6.2.1 too but the same issue persists). All I did was change the version number in our pom file and add the  attribute and implement a few new methods in our MockGrid.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
            <artifactId>gridgain-platform</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

As I run through the relevant testcases, there appears to be an issue starting the grid.

Here's the relevant error (Stack trace available at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a34f9a37a67ea98623b3) . What more do I need to do ? Did any constructors , properties change that I need to affect in our spring config?

Thanks,
Vinay

```
[2014-09-09 17:08:16,481] INFO  GridNodeMonitorImpl - Monitoring Grid: GridKernal [cfg=GridConfiguration [gridName=master-1, execSvc=org.gridgain.grid.thread.GridThreadPoolExecutor@fbf7b8f[Running, pool size = 16, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 8], sysSvc=org.gridgain.grid.thread.GridThreadPoolExecutor@6448f15c[Running, pool size = 16, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 7], mgmtSvc=org.gridgain.grid.thread.GridThreadPoolExecutor@70de0273[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], ggfsSvc=org.gridgain.grid.thread.GridThreadPoolExecutor@7f7305e8[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], restExecSvc=null, p2pSvcShutdown=true, execSvcShutdown=true, sysSvcShutdown=true, mgmtSvcShutdown=true, ggfsSvcShutdown=true, restSvcShutdown=true, lifeCycleEmailNtf=true, p2pSvc=org.gridgain.grid.thread.GridThreadPoolExecutor@588903b6[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], ggHome=null, ggWork=null, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@21ab7757, nodeId=e99a635d-a5ff-48ca-8486-3a9184d072b1, marsh=org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller@b52cf23, marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, jettyPath=null, restEnabled=true, p2pEnabled=false, netTimeout=5000, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, clockSyncSamples=8, clockSyncFreq=120000, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=GridTcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, locPort=47500, locPortRange=100, statsPrintFreq=0, netTimeout=5000, sockTimeout=60000, ackTimeout=5000, maxAckTimeout=600000, joinTimeout=0, hbFreq=5000, maxMissedHbs=10, threadPri=10, storesCleanFreq=60000, reconCnt=10, topHistSize=1000, gridName=master-1, locNodeId=e99a635d-a5ff-48ca-8486-3a9184d072b1, marsh=GridJdkMarshaller [], gridMarsh=org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller@b52cf23, locNode=GridTcpDiscoveryNode [id=e99a635d-a5ff-48ca-8486-3a9184d072b1, addrs=[192.168.1.117, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.1.117:47502, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:47502, /127.0.0.1:47502], discPort=47502, order=3, loc=true, ver=GridProductVersion [major=6, minor=2, maintenance=0, stage=, revTs=1408990498]], locAddr=null, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, ipFinder=GridTcpDiscoveryIpFinderAdapter [shared=false], metricsStore=null, spiState=CONNECTED, ipFinderHasLocAddr=false, recon=true, joinRes=GridTuple [val=null], nodeAuth=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$3@76f073b3, gridStartTime=1410300490132], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=GridTcpCommunicationSpi [srvLsnr=org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi$2@243c29c6, locNodeId=e99a635d-a5ff-48ca-8486-3a9184d072b1, marsh=org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller@b52cf23, locAddr=null, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locPort=47100, locPortRange=100, shmemPort=48100, gridName=master-1, directBuf=true, directSndBuf=false, idleConnTimeout=30000, connBufFlushFreq=100, connBufSize=0, connTimeout=1000, maxConnTimeout=600000, reconCnt=10, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, msgQueueLimit=1024, minBufferedMsgCnt=512, bufSizeRatio=0.8, dualSockConn=false, nioSrvr=GridNioServer [filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.gridgain.grid.util.nio.GridDirectParser@3970a5ee, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], closed=false, directBuf=true, tcpNoDelay=true, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, writeTimeout=5000, idleTimeout=30000, skipWrite=false, locAddr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:47102, order=LITTLE_ENDIAN, sndQueueLimit=1024, directMode=true, metricsLsnr=org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi$3@129dc9b8, msgWriter=org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi$6@35265894, sslFilter=null], shmemSrv=null, tcpNoDelay=true, asyncSnd=true, lsnr=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$3@688177ce, boundTcpPort=47102, boundTcpShmemPort=-1, selectorsCnt=2, addrRslvr=null, nodeIdMsg=org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi$NodeIdMessage@be0aafc, rcvdMsgsCnt=7, sentMsgsCnt=4, rcvdBytesCnt=128650, sentBytesCnt=23197, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@4af98c7b[Count = 0], metricsLsnr=org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi$3@129dc9b8, locks=GridKeyLock [locksSize=0], msgReader=org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi$5@476fcb17, msgWriter=org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi$6@35265894], evtSpi=GridMemoryEventStorageSpi [expireAgeMs=9223372036854775807, expireCnt=10000, filter=null], colSpi=GridPriorityQueueCollisionSpi [parallelJobsNum=95, waitJobsNum=2147483647, runningCnt=0, waitingCnt=0, heldCnt=0, taskPriAttrKey=grid.task.priority, jobPriAttrKey=grid.job.priority, dfltPri=0, starvationInc=1, preventStarvation=true, priComp=null], authSpi=GridNoopAuthenticationSpi [], sesSpi=GridNoopSecureSessionSpi [], deploySpi=GridLocalDeploymentSpi [lsnr=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentLocalStore$LocalDeploymentListener@2da1f51c], swapSpaceSpi=GridNoopSwapSpaceSpi [], addrRslvr=null, cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, smtpHost=null, smtpPort=25, smtpUsername=null, smtpPwd=null, smtpFromEmail=info@gridgain.com, smtpSsl=false, smtpStartTls=false, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, restSecretKey=null, licUrl=null, metricsLogFreq=60000, restTcpHost=null, restTcpPort=11211, restTcpNoDelay=true, restTcpDirectBuf=false, restTcpSndBufSize=0, restTcpRcvBufSize=0, restTcpSndQueueLimit=0, restTcpSelectorCnt=2, restIdleTimeout=7000, restTcpSslEnabled=false, restTcpSslClientAuth=false, restTcpSslCtxFactory=null, restPortRange=100, clientMsgInterceptor=null, drRcvHubCfg=null, drSndHubCfg=null, dataCenterId=0, securityCred=null, hadoopCfg=null, clientCfg=null, portableCfg=null], log=GridLoggerProxy [gridName=master-1, id8=e99a635d], gridName=master-1, kernalMBean=org.gridgain:grid=master-1,group=Kernal,name=GridKernal, locNodeMBean=org.gridgain:grid=master-1,group=Kernal,name=GridLocalNodeMetrics, pubExecSvcMBean=org.gridgain:grid=master-1,group=Thread Pools,name=GridExecutionExecutor, sysExecSvcMBean=org.gridgain:grid=master-1,group=Thread Pools,name=GridSystemExecutor, mgmtExecSvcMBean=org.gridgain:grid=master-1,group=Thread Pools,name=GridManagementExecutor, p2PExecSvcMBean=org.gridgain:grid=master-1,group=Thread Pools,name=GridClassLoadingExecutor, restExecSvcMBean=null, startTime=1410300494574, rsrcCtx=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.resource.GridSpringResourceContextImpl@5268b5c8, updateNtfTimer=null, starveTimer=null, licTimer=null, metricsLogTimer=null, errOnStop=false, scheduler=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridSchedulerImpl@587687bc, security=null, portables=null, drPool=null, gw=GridKernalGatewayImpl [state=STARTED, gridName=master-1, stackTrace=java.lang.Throwable
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.stackTrace(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:137)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.writeLock(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:105)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridKernal.start(GridKernal.java:515)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx$GridNamedInstance.start0(GridGainEx.java:1898)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx$GridNamedInstance.start(GridGainEx.java:1232)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start0(GridGainEx.java:775)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:472)
at org.gridgain.grid.GridGainSpring.start(GridGainSpring.java:73)
at org.gridgain.grid.GridSpringBean.afterPropertiesSet(GridSpringBean.java:145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at com.mycompany.enterprise.gridgain.license.GridInstance.initialize(GridInstance.java:88)
at com.mycompany.enterprise.gridgain.license.GridNodeMonitorIT.testMasterNodeDiscoversWorkerNodesWhenStartedAfterWorkers(GridNodeMonitorIT.java:173)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an exception during the start. Stacktrace you see is just a field which is printed out when Grid.toString is called. Thanks for pointing this out, we will fix it in the next version.

Thanks!